# fresh installed mysql and mysql-server but failed to start server

Tags: mysql, linux, fedora

I am new to Linux and tried to install mysql in my local box

I googled a lot and follow the instruction but none of them works

some people recommand [this](http://www.if-not-true-then-false.com/2010/install-mysql-on-fedora-centos-red-hat-rhel/)" but it did not work for me and system give me warning about this is not a official version.

Basically what I did was:

1. yum install mysql mysql-version
   succeed without error, version is 5.5.28
2. systemctl start mysqld.service
   here it threw out error:
   Job failed. See system logs and 'systemctl status' for details.

I am using Fedora 16 (3.1.0-7.fc16.i686)

Thank you in advance

Comment: why we should not try this in [serverfault](http://serverfault.com/questions/379176/fedora-cant-find-mysql-service)  @Nuda Lu

Answer (score 0):

Could you try running

yum groupinstall "MySQL Database"

then run

service mysqld start

and see the outcome. Assuming you are running as root or with root permissions.

Comment: same result "Redirecting to /bin/systemctl  start mysqld.service
Job failed. See system logs and 'systemctl status' for details"

Comment: Try running the service again so it generates the error then run; "cat /var/log/syslog" and post the results so we know what's going on.

Comment: there is not "syslog" under the directory. The closest one is called "mysqld.log" but it is empty

Answer (score 0):

Got the EXACT same problem. It seems there is an issue regarding the permissions of the /var/lib/mysql directory.

This nailed it for me:

```
chown -R mysql.mysql /var/lib/mysql
```

Source: http://www.vivaolinux.com.br/dica/Como-solucionar-ERROR-2002-Cant-connect-to-local-MySQL-server